# How should I limit the slow disconnect of thousands of tcp connections?

Tags: sockets, go, tcp, linux-kernel, ipv4

I have a golang program running on centos that usually has around 5k tcp clients connected. Every once in a while this number goes to around 15k for about an hour and still everything is fine.

The program has a slow shutdown mode where it stops accepting new clients and slowly kills all currently connected clients over the course of 20 mins. During these slow shutdown periods if the machine has 15k clients, sometimes I get:

```
Wed Oct 31 21:28:23 2018] net_ratelimit: 482 callbacks suppressed
[Wed Oct 31 21:28:23 2018] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Wed Oct 31 21:28:23 2018] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Wed Oct 31 21:28:23 2018] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
```

I have tried adding:

```
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=5000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -f /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And these values are set, I see them with their correct new values. A typical sockstat is:

```
cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 31682
TCP: inuse 17286 orphan 5 tw 3874 alloc 31453 mem 15731
UDP: inuse 8 mem 3
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

And ideas how to stop the too many orphaned socket error and crash? Should I increase the 20 min slow shutdown period to 40 mins? Increase tcp_mem? Thanks!

Comment: Some hint about the same problem here: https://serverfault.com/questions/624911/what-does-tcp-too-many-orphaned-sockets-mean

Comment: You do not actually appear to deal with orphaned sockets ([here](https://serverfault.com/a/624940/118848)'s how); and in your `sockstat` output there are only 5 of them. The number of sockets in the `TIME_WAIT` state is indeed large (3.8k) but that's not indicative of any real problem (other than a high rate of connect/disconnect churn).

Comment: Also see the description of `tcp_max_orphans` [here](https://www.frozentux.net/ipsysctl-tutorial/chunkyhtml/tcpvariables.html#AEN388) — it actually hints at that to properly tackle this problem, you should look at decreasing `tcp_fin_timeout` and/or `tcp_orphan_retries`.

Comment: And also note that IIRC an orphan socket means that our (your) side has properly closed a connection but the other side did not (that is, we have sent `FIN` there but have not heard back an `ACK` for it), and so the kernel detaches the socket from our process and tries to deal with it according to the TCP stack. Hence the problem with high rate of orphans might indicate networking problems, and you might need to somehow check that.

Comment: I see, the way I’m ending the connections is with if LongShutdown {
    if rand.Intn(15) == 5 {
      c.Close()
    }
  }   In a main loop so, with some random chance, a certain % are told to disconnect slowly until there are none left. But I must be going too fast. I need to delete a few connections and then just wait. Pause. Let the FIN’s get their ACKs before deleteing anymore.